# Disabling a Button in HTML. New Coder

Tags: html, css

so I'm currently trying to disable a button but also have the same button type. If anyone can help me with examples it would be great! Thanks so much to the ones that help! :D

```html
<!--- I want this one to be the working button. --->

          <a
            class="project-link"
            target="_blank"
            href="/gimkit"
            >Use <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> </a
          >

<!--- this one to be the button that doesn't work. (disabled)
 --->
          <a
            class="project-link"
            target="_blank"
            href="/support"
            >Help <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> </a
          >
```

I want something like this, but have the Help Button with a question mark to be faded instead of the normal button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXRMz.png

Comment: Provide the code for your the disable button. Is it a button or a hyperlink?

Comment: It looks like you have it written as a button, but in <a> tags making it look like a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the button-elements answer is the best solution.
But if you really want to stick with the Anchor-Tags, you could also try to add a helper css class. For example you can use something like this:

```
<a
        class="project-link disabled"
        target="_blank"
        href="/support"
        onclick="return false;"
        >Help <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> </a
      >
```

And the css of the .disabled class could look like this:

```
.project-link.disabled{
   opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `<button>` element, just add the `disabled` property:

```html
<button type="button" disabled>Help</button>
```